# Using ' ' in mysql procedure in mysql select statement, but getting Invalid column name error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm currently trying to creature a procedure where I am using ' ' to hardcode certain values.

here is a part of my select statement

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TWSValuationStagingGAPC]
AS
SET LANGUAGE english
DECLARE @date char(10);
DECLARE @transactiondate char(10);
DECLARE @tempDate DATETIME = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 23);
DECLARE @tableName as char(50);
DECLARE @currentYear as char(4);
DECLARE @currentMonth as char(50);
DECLARE @dummy as char(50);
DECLARE @risk           as char(50);
DECLARE @TopDmValuation as char(50);
DECLARE @AKT_SUL_TAE    as char(50);
DECLARE @DIS            as char(50);
DECLARE @GAPC           as char(50);
DECLARE @WAISOL         as char(50);
DECLARE @N030           as char(50);
DECLARE @S030           as char(50);
DECLARE @SDIT           as char(50);
DECLARE @RUNSOL         as char(50);
DECLARE @T14U_01        as char(50);
DECLARE @t              as char(50);
DECLARE @f              as char(50);
DECLARE @0              as char(50);
SET @date = EOMONTH(@tempDate, -1);
SET @transactiondate= dateadd(day,1,EOMONTH(@tempDate, -1));
SET @currentYear = DATEPART ( yyyy , GETDATE());  
SET @currentMonth = datename (m, getDate());
SET @tableName = 'input' + @currentYear + @currentMonth; 
SET @dummy = 'dummy';
SET @risk  = 'risk';
SET @TopDmValuation  = 'TopDmValuation';
SET @AKT_SUL_TAE  = 'AKT_SUL_TAE';
SET @DIS  = 'DIS';
SET @GAPC  = 'GAPC';
SET @WAISOL  = 'WAISOL';
SET @N030  = 'N030';
SET @S030  = 'S030';
SET @SDIT  = 'SDIT';
SET @RUNSOL  = 'RUNSOL';
SET @T14U_01  = 'T14U_01';
SET @t  = 't';
SET @f  = 'f';
SET @0 = '0';
DECLARE @longstring nvarchar(max);
EXEC('
BEGIN
Insert Into ValuationStaging.[dbo].' + @tableName + ' 
select Distinct 
' + @dummy + ' as UID
,null as DMCREATETIME
,null as COBABS
,null as COBABSDATE
,null as COBPCT
,null as COBSTEP
,null as AGECHILDVESTING
,lcv.PREMIUMTIMESPEC_SELECTEDENDAGE as AGEPREMIUMEND
,lcv.BENEFITTIMESPEC_SELECTEDENDAGE as AGETERMINATIONBENEFIT
,lcv.RISKTIMESPEC_SELECTEDENDAGE as AGETERMINATIONRISK
,lcv.BENEFITTIMESPEC_SELECTEDSTARTAGE as AGEVESTING
,ob.BENEFIT as BENEFIT
,null as BENEFITRELATIONPC
,null as BONUSDISTRIBUTIONRULE
,null as COBTYPE
,p.[CENTRALREGISTRATION_REGISTRATION] as CPRNUMBERLIFE1
,null as CPRNUMBERLIFE2
,let.COMMITDATE as EVENTCOMMITDATE
,let.EVENTDATE as EVENTDATE
,lei.LIFEEVENTSORTNO as EVENTSORTNO
,null as FREQUENCYANNUITY
,lpv.SELECTEDPREMIUMFREQUENCY as FREQUENCYPREMIUM
,lcv.LIFECOVERSTATE as INFORCEINDICATOR
,null as INSURANCECLASS
,null as LENGHTOFINSTALLMENT
,cf.NAME as LIFEBASIS
,lcv.uid as LIFECOVERVERSIONUID
,let.uid as LIFEEVENTTRANSUID
,lpa.uid as LIFEPACKAGEUID
,lpv.uid as LIFEPOLICYVERSIONUID
,' + @risk + '  as LINEOFBUSINESS
,ob.uid as OPTIMIZATIONBALANCEUID
,null as ORIGINALINCEPTIONDATE
,null as ORIGINALPREMIUMTYPEMEMBERSYSTEM
,SUBSTRING(lpa.LEGALGROUPID, 4, 1) as PARTICIPATIONGROUPCOST
,SUBSTRING(lpa.LEGALGROUPID, 1, 1) as PARTICIPATIONGROUPINTEREST
,SUBSTRING(lpa.LEGALGROUPID, 2, 1) as PARTICIPATIONGROUPRISK
,null as PAYMENTDATE
,lp.id as POLICYNUMBER
,PREMIUM as PREMIUM
,lpv.LIFEPOLICYSTATUS  as PREMIUMSTATUSMEMBERSYSTEM
,null as REGULATIONSNUMBER
,ob.FIRSTORDERBALANCE as RESERVE1ORDER
,ob.SECONDORDERBALANCE as RESERVE2ORDER
,ob.RESERVEACCOUNT_UID  as RESERVEACCOUNTUID
,lcv.BENEFITTIMESPEC_SELECTEDSTARTAGE as RETIREMENTAGEINPUT
,ob.GLDIM1 as REWARDID
,null as SAVINGSCOVER
,null as SHADOW
,0 as SOLIDARYPRICE -- always 0 for non solidaryCovers
,null as STARTMONTHANNUITY
,null as STARTMONTHPREMIUM
,null as STATEMEMBERSYSTEM
,null as SUBSCRIPTIONDATE
,null as SUMATRISKDEAD
,null as SUMATRISKDEAD_CO
,null as SUMATRISKDISABILITY
,null as TAXCODE
,null as TECHNICALBENEFITSTARTDATE
,null as TECHNICALPREMIUMENDDATE
,null as TECHNICALRISKENDDATE
,null as EXPIRYMONTH
,' + @TopDmValuation + ' as DTYPE
,SETTLEMENTFEE as SETTLEMENTFEE
,null as BONUS
```

However mysql for some reason thinks I'm refering to a column named "dummy", as can be seen in below error code. and I'm not quite sure why.  or how I can get it to use 'dummy' in the column uid instead.

```
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 150
    Invalid column name 'GAPC'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 150
    Invalid column name 'GAPC'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 179
    Invalid column name 'DIS'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 180
    Invalid column name 'GAPC'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 181
    Invalid column name 'GAPC'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 182
    Invalid column name 'WAISOL'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 183
    Invalid column name 'N030'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 183
    Invalid column name 'SDIT'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 184
    Invalid column name 'S030'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 184
    Invalid column name 'RUNSOL'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 186
    Invalid column name 'T14U_01'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 187
    Invalid column name 't'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 187
    Invalid column name 'f'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
    Invalid column name 'dummy'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
    Invalid column name 'risk'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 70
    Invalid column name 'TopDmValuation'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 107
    Invalid column name 'AKT_SUL_TAE'.
    Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
```

I also get the same error in the where clause where I am using

```
 and ( lcv.LIFECOVERTYPEREF IN (' + @GAPC + ') or lcv.lifecovertyperef is null)
```

Comment: SSMS is used with SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: String literals need to be in single quotes. But you should rather use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with parameters instead of string concatenation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that instead of declaring variables I wanted to use string literals of, I could just use string literals directly by using double single quotes.
my select now looks like this:

```
EXEC('
BEGIN
Insert Into ValuationStaging.[dbo].' + @tableName + ' 
select Distinct 
''dummy'' as UID
,null as DMCREATETIME
,null as COBABS
,null as COBABSDATE
,null as COBPCT
,null as COBSTEP
,null as AGECHILDVESTING
,lcv.PREMIUMTIMESPEC_SELECTEDENDAGE as AGEPREMIUMEND
,lcv.BENEFITTIMESPEC_SELECTEDENDAGE as AGETERMINATIONBENEFIT
,lcv.RISKTIMESPEC_SELECTEDENDAGE as AGETERMINATIONRISK
,lcv.BENEFITTIMESPEC_SELECTEDSTARTAGE as AGEVESTING
,ob.BENEFIT as BENEFIT
,null as BENEFITRELATIONPC
,null as BONUSDISTRIBUTIONRULE
,null as COBTYPE
,p.[CENTRALREGISTRATION_REGISTRATION] as CPRNUMBERLIFE1
,null as CPRNUMBERLIFE2
,let.COMMITDATE as EVENTCOMMITDATE
,let.EVENTDATE as EVENTDATE
,lei.LIFEEVENTSORTNO as EVENTSORTNO
,null as FREQUENCYANNUITY
,lpv.SELECTEDPREMIUMFREQUENCY as FREQUENCYPREMIUM
,lcv.LIFECOVERSTATE as INFORCEINDICATOR
,null as INSURANCECLASS
,null as LENGHTOFINSTALLMENT
,cf.NAME as LIFEBASIS
,lcv.uid as LIFECOVERVERSIONUID
,let.uid as LIFEEVENTTRANSUID
,lpa.uid as LIFEPACKAGEUID
,lpv.uid as LIFEPOLICYVERSIONUID
,''risk''  as LINEOFBUSINESS
,ob.uid as OPTIMIZATIONBALANCEUID
,null as ORIGINALINCEPTIONDATE
,null as ORIGINALPREMIUMTYPEMEMBERSYSTEM
,SUBSTRING(lpa.LEGALGROUPID, 4, 1) as PARTICIPATIONGROUPCOST
,SUBSTRING(lpa.LEGALGROUPID, 1, 1) as PARTICIPATIONGROUPINTEREST
,SUBSTRING(lpa.LEGALGROUPID, 2, 1) as PARTICIPATIONGROUPRISK
,null as PAYMENTDATE
,lp.id as POLICYNUMBER
,PREMIUM as PREMIUM
,lpv.LIFEPOLICYSTATUS  as PREMIUMSTATUSMEMBERSYSTEM
,null as REGULATIONSNUMBER
,ob.FIRSTORDERBALANCE as RESERVE1ORDER
,ob.SECONDORDERBALANCE as RESERVE2ORDER
,ob.RESERVEACCOUNT_UID  as RESERVEACCOUNTUID
,lcv.BENEFITTIMESPEC_SELECTEDSTARTAGE as RETIREMENTAGEINPUT
,ob.GLDIM1 as REWARDID
,null as SAVINGSCOVER
,null as SHADOW
,0 as SOLIDARYPRICE -- always 0 for non solidaryCovers
,null as STARTMONTHANNUITY
,null as STARTMONTHPREMIUM
,null as STATEMEMBERSYSTEM
,null as SUBSCRIPTIONDATE
,null as SUMATRISKDEAD
,null as SUMATRISKDEAD_CO
,null as SUMATRISKDISABILITY
,null as TAXCODE
,null as TECHNICALBENEFITSTARTDATE
,null as TECHNICALPREMIUMENDDATE
,null as TECHNICALRISKENDDATE
,null as EXPIRYMONTH
,''TopDmValuation'' as DTYPE
```